# RavenDB Querying to check Username and Password

Tags: c#, passwords, ravendb

I'm fairly new to C# and RavenDB, so please excuse my lack of understanding.

I currently have a Windows Form Application. In one of the forms, I have two text boxes and one button. These two text boxes serve as the username and password inputs and the button is obviously there so that the user can login. When the user clicks on the button, a method is called and saves the content of the two inputs in two string variables.

At the moment, in my RavenDB Database, I have created two samples of username and password.

How do I appropriately check whether the username and password given from the user exists in the database.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to answer this question.

a) You can query for multiple properties using the Linq provider

```
session.Query<User>().Where(user=> user.Name = username && user.Password = pass).ToList();
```

b) The problem with this is that this assumes that you are storing the password as plain text in the database, which you should **never** do.
You can see how we implemented that in RaccoonBlog's RavenDB's sample application:

https://github.com/ayende/RaccoonBlog/blob/master/src/RaccoonBlog.Web/Models/User.cs

https://github.com/ayende/RaccoonBlog/blob/master/RaccoonBlog.Web/Areas/Admin/Controllers/LoginController.cs

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of good security practice you don't store passwords at all, rather you you store the password's hash.

**To store your password**

1. Read the values on the server and generate a hashcode of the password. You should use crypto functions to generate hash (such as via [SHA256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256.aspx))
2. Store a document in Raven DB of type User with his username and hashed password

**To check if the user with the passed credentials is in the database**

1. Query Raven DB and look for the user with the given name and password hash.

Sample code

```
var user = session.Query<User>()
    .Where(u => u.UserName == "Alice" && u.HashedPassword == "hashPwd");
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to get started in that case. I have a class called: UserLogin.cs and in there are two properties; Username and Password. At the moment, there are two UserLogins, each one with a Username and Password.

What shall I do exactly in this case to get it all working?

Comment: @Subby, check the links Ayende has posted. You should have two classes, first one will hold data (your UserLogin as far as I got it, better rename it to User) and the second one that actually does authentication, such as LoginController